# How do I open a link in the same window and tab using the onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, onclick

I have a page that has multiple divs. I want to get some information from my database to display in some of those divs and I also want it to be displayed as I click on a link to the home div.

I also need the page to be refreshed or reopened in the same window (not in a new page or tab). Last of all, I need the page to be in the home div.

I tried the code below and it didn't work:

```
<a href="#home" onclick="window.open('index.jsp#home')" >home</a>

<a href="#home" onclick="location.reload()">home</a>

<a href="#home" onclick="location.href='index.jsp'">home</a>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used this and it worked

```
<a href="#" class="home_btn" onclick="location.reload();location.href='index.jsp'">منوی اصلی</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

change your :

```
onclick="window.open('index.jsp#home')" >home</a>
```

to

```
onclick="parent.location='index.jsp#home'">home</a>
```

no need to reload.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
<input id="but1" type="button" value="click"></div>

function loadIndex() {
    window.location.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u5nmt/";
}

document.getElementById("but1").addEventListener("click", loadIndex, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u5nmt/)

remember jsfiddle is in frames

Answer (score 0):

The problem with changing `location.href` to the current URL with a hash value is that the page won't reload but jump to the given ID.

If you really want to jump to the home div then you can just jump with `location.href='index.jsp'` and edit your index file
 to set `location.href = '#home'` on load.

If you want to be able to pass information across to the newly loaded page (to provide a specific id) you could use the query string instead, e.g. to jump page use `location.href = 'index.jsp?loaddiv=foo`

Then once the page loads read the query string and use the value to jump to the requested div, e.g. 
     `location.search = '#foo'`

For details on extracting values from the query string see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: i used this and worked
    <a href="#" class="home_btn" onclick="location.reload();location.href='index.jsp'">Home</a>